# Trying to iterate through a mesh structure results in "borrowed value does not live long enough"

Tags: iterator, rust, borrowing

I am trying to create a data structure that can store monitor location data.

The approach I'm taking is that each screen has references to 4 neighbors stored in a `HashMap<Direction, Rc<RefCell<Screen>>>`.

What I'm struggling with is how to "move"/iterate in a direction until I reach the edge of the mesh:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, Default)]
pub struct ScreenCoord {
    left: i32,
    right: i32,
    bottom: i32,
    top: i32,
}

impl ScreenCoord {
    fn new_primary_from_dimensions(width: i32, height: i32) -> ScreenCoord {
        ScreenCoord {
            left: 0,
            right: width,
            top: 0,
            bottom: height,
        }
    }
}

pub struct ScreenNetwork {
    primary_screen: Rc<RefCell<Screen>>,
}

impl ScreenNetwork {
    pub fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> ScreenNetwork {
        ScreenNetwork {
            primary_screen: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Screen::new(
                ScreenCoord::new_primary_from_dimensions(width, height),
            ))),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_screen(&mut self, new_width: i32, new_height: i32, direction: Direction) {
        let mut new_scrn = Screen::new(ScreenCoord::new_primary_from_dimensions(
            new_width, new_height,
        ));
        let mut original_screen = &self.primary_screen;

        while let Some(next) = original_screen.borrow().neighbours.get(&direction) {
            original_screen = next;
        }

        // Do stuff with original_screen

        // new_scrn.neighbours.insert(Direction::from_u8((direction.clone() as u8) ^ 0b11).unwrap(), original_screen.clone());
        // original_screen.borrow_mut().neighbours.insert(direction, Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_scrn)));
    }
}

/// Screen with information about adjacent screens
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct Screen {
    neighbours: HashMap<Direction, Rc<RefCell<Screen>>>,
    coordinates: ScreenCoord,
}

impl Screen {
    pub fn new(coord: ScreenCoord) -> Screen {
        Screen {
            coordinates: coord,
            neighbours: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Hash, Eq, Clone)]
pub enum Direction {
    Left = 0,
    Top,
    Bottom,
    Right,
}

fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a7269f3bfa975cd17c3353a3e17dbb9e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:43:32
   |
43 |         while let Some(next) = original_screen.borrow().neighbours.get(&direction) {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                                |
   |                                temporary value does not live long enough
...
51 |     }
   |     - temporary value needs to live until here
```

I understand why the error is happening, but I have no clue as to how I can fix it. I tried to clone `original_screen` and `next`, but then the compiler complains that I am trying to set `original_screen` while still borrowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Rc`, so take advantage of it. Generally speaking, taking a reference to a `Rc` is asking for problems.

First try: clone `Rc` when needed:

```
let mut original_screen = self.primary_screen.clone();

while let Some(next) = original_screen.borrow().neighbours.get(&direction) {
    original_screen = next.clone();
}
```

It fails with the message:

> cannot assign to `original_screen` because it is borrowed

True enough: having a borrow in the `while` condition will not let you update it, but it can be rewritten easily:

```
loop {
    if let Some(next) = original_screen.borrow().neighbours.get(&direction) {
         original_screen = next.clone()
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

That code is equivalent, and indeed it fails with the same error message! But now we are closer to a solution:

```
loop {
    let next = if let Some(next) = original_screen.borrow().neighbours.get(&direction) {
         next.clone()
    } else {
        break;
    };
    original_screen = next;
}
```

Now it compiles because the assignment is done after the borrow is released.